# Webpack errors on Publish using Angular 4.2.5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, primeng

I created an app with the SPA Templates.  The Angular app is using the [primeng](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/) components for the UI. In order to get the bootstrap, fontawesome and primeng themes running I ran `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`  so that I could add the css files to the `nonTreeShakableModules` array.  Everything seems to work until I publish.

When I attempt to publish I get the following error

```
    ERROR in ./$$_gendir/~/primeng/components/menu/menu.ngfactory.ts
Module parse failed: .\$$_gendir\node_modules\primeng\components\menu\menu.ngfactory.ts Unexpected token (14:32)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import * as i3 from '@angular/router';
| import * as i4 from 'primeng/components/dom/domhandler';
| export const MenuModuleNgFactory:i0.NgModuleFactory<i1.MenuModule> = i0.?cmf(i1.MenuModule,
|     ([] as any[]),(_l:any) => {
|       return i0.?mod([i0.?mpd(512,i0.ComponentFactoryResolver,i0.?CodegenComponentFactoryResolver,
 @ ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/components/locations/locations.component.ngfactory.ts 9:0-99
 @ ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/components/list/list.component.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.server.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts
```

I have this error for every primeng component that is used.

Comment: Cool Java andere jsf is replacing .Net

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing this because The ASP.NET core 2.0 / Angular Template uses different typescript loaders for development and for production : `awesome-typescript-loader` and `angular2-template-loader` in development, and `@ngtools/webpack` in production.

From my experience, `@ngtools/webpack`  doesn't do well with loading some third party angular components. You could try using `awesome-typescript-loader` and `angular2-template-loader` for both development and production.